# how to get text from a window with specific HWND?

Tags: c++, winapi, hwnd

I'm new to win32 programming and haven't worked around with cpp for a long time. What I intend to do is to get a window's HWND via spy++, and get the text of this window. The problem is that  I don't know how to create a HWND object, could anyone give me some idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just in case you are unaware the HWND will change every time the windows is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the numeric value of the HWND, you can cast it to the right type.  Start with an integer of the right size, e.g.:

```
uintptr_t numeric_hwnd = 0x987654;
HWND hwnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(numeric_hwnd);
```